# When would `if False` execute in Python?

Tags: python

While browsing some code, I came across this line:

```
if False: #shedskin
```

I understand that [Shedskin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) is a kind of Python -> C++ compiler, but I can't understand that line.

Shouldn't `if False:` never execute? What's going on here?

For context:

This is the whole block:

```
if False: # shedskin
    AStar(SQ_MapHandler([1], 1, 1)).findPath(SQ_Location(1,1), SQ_Location(1,1))
```

[More context is on Google Code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#9DqINQj3nPs/trunk/examples/astar.py&ct=rc&cd=1&q=astar%20lang%3a%5Epython%24&l=34) (scroll down all the way).

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Are you saying that the `if False:` was put in by a developer as a workaround for some Shedskin parsing behavior?

Comment: @Inerdia I have added context.

Comment: @goldsz That's part of what I would like to know.

Comment: If the line purpose is only to add context (e.g., for _shed skin_), I suggest it'd be less confusing (more Pythonic) to add this line after an `if __name__ == "__main__":` at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't execute, because it isn't supposed to. The `if False:` is there to intentionally prevent the next line from executing, because that code's only purpose is seemingly to help Shed Skin infer type information about the argument to the `AStar()` function.

You can see another example of this [in `httplib`](http://code.google.com/p/rpython-libs/source/browse/trunk/lib/httplib.py?r=10#1116):

```
#   Useless stuff to help type info
if False :
    conn._set_tunnel("example.com")
```

Comment: This seems like the most likely explanation to me given the Shed Skin project description. I believe the Wing Python IDE does something similar, you can give its code completion engine clues by sprinkling your code with `assert isinstance(foo, bar)`.

Answer (score 7):

It will never get executed. It's one way to temporarily disable part of the code.

Comment: It's worth noting that using `if 0` will actually remove the code path at compile time, while `if False` cannot, since `False` could be reassigned (at least in Python 2.7).

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, it *could* get executed:

```
True, False = False, True
if False: print 'foo'
```

But typically this will be used to temporarily disable a code path.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in assuming that this will never evaluate to true.  This is sometimes done when the programmer has a lot of debugging code but does not want to remove the debugging code in a release, so they just put `if False:` above it all.

Answer (score 2):

not enough reputation to comment yet apparently, but tim stone's answer is correct. suppose we have a function like this:

```
def blah(a,b):
    return a+b
```

now in order to perform type inference, there has to be at least one call to blah, or it becomes impossible to know the types of the arguments at compile-time.

for a stand-alone program, this not a problem, since everything that has to be compiled for it to run is called indirectly from somewhere..

for an extension module, calls can come from the 'outside', so sometimes we have to add a 'fake' call to a function for type inference to become possible.. hence the 'if False'.

in the shedskin example set there are a few programs that are compiled as extension modules, in order to be combined with for example pygame or multiprocessing.